Meaning of the Proto-Indo-European word *swe-?
I'm writing a paper and in need of help. I have found that PIE word *swe- is a third person reflexive pronoun and origin of English self.
However, at some places I found that *s(w)e- means “separate, apart”. Like here (wiktionary, etymology of German selbst) "self" and here (cooljugator.com, etymology of English self). Now, this could be huge for my theory, however, I cannot find the source anywhere, or any source material, etc. to cite and backup my idea.

Wiktionary is often a good source for Proto-Indo-European things, since it provides a big crowdsourced list of reflexes in different descendant languages, and citations to different etymological dictionaries where you can research further.
In particular, note descendants like Greek ἴδιος "personal, private" (hence "idiom"), Latin sōlus "alone" (hence "sole" and "solo"), and the Latin sē- prefix Sir Cornflakes mentioned (as in "seclude", "seduce", "secure").
However, it's not clear if this was a meaning found in the Proto-Indo-European ancestor, or an independent development in different branches. The progression from "self" to "alone" is fairly straightforward; compare English "by yourself".

The ‘separate, apart’ meaning is often cited in PIE kinship terms containing this word, like *su̯e-k̑rúh₂-s- ‘mother-in-law’ (< ‘having her own/separate head [of family]’, i.e., belonging to the ‘other’ family, not mine; a u-stem from *su̯e- + *k̑erh₂- ‘head’ [as in κέρας], with laryngeal metathesis of *su̯e-k̑rh₂-ú- to *su̯e-k̑rúh₂-). Such etymologies explicitly require the ‘separate’ meaning to have been present in PIE itself.

@JanusBahsJacquet That would make a good answer!

The meaning "separate, apart" is reconstructed from the Latin prefix sē in verbs like secludo "to seclude". This prefix clearly has the meaning "separate, apart" and it is traced to the same root as English self.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question (I'm a philosopher, not a linguist), but can we connect se as unstressed reflexive pronoun and prefix se-? One good example I found meanwhile, in Etymological Dictionary of Latin by de Vaan, is per se.

Unstressed se is from the same root AFAIK, but I don't know how far one has to go back in history to connect it with the prefix sē. In PIE all later verbal prefixes were particles, and there weren't prepositions either.
